# Загрузила сайт на Хостинг, не работает часть скриптов

Tags: javascript, html, css

В общем на локальном сервере все нормально работает. Загрузила сайт на Хостинг и проблема в том, что не правильно работает animate.css и Wow.js
К тому же стрелка (pageup) вообще не видит стили с css файла.
При этом если зайти с мобильного устройства, то все работает как и должно, даже если галочку версия для пк поставить, так же не правильно работает гугл карта, вот сравните, зайдите с телефона и с пк и сразу поймёте в чем проблема. И вот как это решить? Я не понимаю(
Вот ссылка на сайт http://w9137625.beget.tech/

Учебная работа

Answer (score 2):

Проблему смогла решить отчисткой кеша в браузере -_-